# Drools Upgrade to 7.73.0 is breaking our Drools-JSR94 implementation (drools-jsr94-7.2.0.Final.jar)

Tags: java, drools

Our company has mandated a drools upgrade for security reasons.
We have code that depends on drools-jsr94-7.2.0.Final.jar

Upgrading drools libs to 7.73.0 causes code in ***drools-jsr94-7.2.0.Final.jar*** to break.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.drools.core.reteoo.KieComponentFactory.setHandleFactoryProvider(Lorg/drools/core/spi/FactHandleFactory;)V
 at org.drools.jsr94.rules.admin.RuleExecutionSetImpl.<init>(RuleExecutionSetImpl.java:108) ~[drools-jsr94-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
 at org.drools.jsr94.rules.admin.LocalRuleExecutionSetProviderImpl.createRuleExecutionSet(LocalRuleExecutionSetProviderImpl.java:232) ~[drools-jsr94-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
 at org.drools.jsr94.rules.admin.LocalRuleExecutionSetProviderImpl.createRuleExecutionSet(LocalRuleExecutionSetProviderImpl.java:175) ~[drools-jsr94-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
```

What options do we have? Is there a replacement available for the drools-jsr94 rule engine API that provides the same functionality and works with drools 7.73.0?

Ideally we would like to avoid re-writing our rules, which would introduce a data migration issue for our customers.

Before upgrading, our drools version was 6.2.0.Final.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: If you're upgrading drools, you need to upgrade _all_ of the drools components. Not just some of them. Since the jsr94 subproject  appears abandoned, you'll need to either find the latest version of Drools that still has the missing artifacts (I will guess 7.43 if it's even in the 7.x branch ... seems likely not), or reevaluate why you need that subproject at all.

Comment: Also you neglected to mention what you're upgrading _from_.

Comment: Hi Roddy, thanks for the response. Before upgrading, our drools version was 6.2.0. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should really consider using the KIE API in place of the old JSR94 SPI.

Using the KIE API ensures you have a fully documented and access not only to Drools usage use-cases but also for the projects part of the KIE ecosystem.

You could reference Chapter 3 "KIE" in the Drools documentation, specifically inside [3.2.6. Build, Deploy and Utilize Examples](https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_kieexamplessection) you can find several example of KieBase/KieSession.