Is Drools 8.x JSR94 compliant?
Drools 8.x distribution doesn't contain jar with name jsr94. With Drools 7.x distribution, drools-jsr94.jar is provided. The 7.x documentation mentions that the jar drools-jsr94.jar is the JSR-94 compliant implementation, this is essentially a layer over the drools-compiler component.
With 8.x drools distribution, there is no such jar provided. They haven't mentioned anything related to it in 8.x documentation and release notes.
If Drools 8.x is JSR94 compliant, are there any examples that shows the sample code for using drools 8.x with JSR94 compliant way.


With 8.x drools distribution, there is no such jar provided

Correct, the JSR-94 module was removed from 7.5.0.Final.
You should really consider using the KIE API in place of the old JSR-94 SPI, as detailed in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73578636/893991
